# RegexpParser crashes Python 3.8.6 kernel in JupyterLab

Tags: python-3.x, macos, nltk, jupyter-lab

I am parsing chunks of pos-tagged text in JupyterLabs.

NLTK can run on Python<3.5 and >3.8 according to its faq.

I can return pos-tagged text just fine. But when I want to return parsed chunks, it crashes python.

I am running MacOS 11.1, Python 3.8.6, Jupyterlab 3.0.0, and nltk 3.5

```
    from nltk import *

text = """The Buddha, the Godhead, resides quite as comfortably in the circuits of a digital
computer or the gears of a cycle transmission as he does at the top of a mountain
or in the petals of a flower. To think otherwise is to demean the Buddha...which is
to demean oneself."""

sentence_re = r'''(?x)      
      ([A-Z])(\.[A-Z])+\.?  
    | \w+(-\w+)*            
    | \$?\d+(\.\d+)?%?      
    | \.\.\.                
    | [][.,;"'?():-_`]      
'''

grammar = r"""
    NBAR:
        {<NN.*|JJ>*<NN.*>}  # Nouns and Adjectives, terminated with Nouns
        
    NP:
        {<NBAR>}
        {<NBAR><IN><NBAR>}  # Above, connected with in/of/etc...
"""
chunker = RegexpParser(grammar)
toks = word_tokenize(text)
postoks = pos_tag(toks)
```

All is fine until I want to parse the chunks with RegexpParser. At which point, it crashes the kernel.

```
chunker.parse(postoks)
```

beginning of the crash report:

```
Process:               Python [1549]
Path:                  /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            org.python.python
Version:               3.8.6 (3.8.6)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        Python [1522]
Responsible:           Terminal [416]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-12-29 15:34:13.546 -0500
OS Version:            macOS 11.1 (20C69)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        8EEE2257-0986-3569-AA83-52641AF02282


Time Awake Since Boot: 1200 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
abort() called
```

end of the crash report:

```
External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 4
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 4785
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=835.0M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=835.0M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=1.5G written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=1.5G(100%)
 
                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Activity Tracing                   256K        1 
Dispatch continuations            64.0M        1 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        1 
MALLOC                           150.1M       37 
MALLOC guard page                   24K        5 
MALLOC_MEDIUM (reserved)         960.0M        8         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
STACK GUARD                         72K       18 
Stack                             86.6M       18 
VM_ALLOCATE                      182.5M      359 
VM_ALLOCATE (reserved)           128.0M        2         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
__DATA                            16.1M      460 
__DATA_CONST                      11.8M      200 
__DATA_DIRTY                       509K       87 
__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 
__LINKEDIT                       506.1M      241 
__OBJC_RO                         60.5M        1 
__OBJC_RW                         2452K        2 
__TEXT                           329.5M      432 
__UNICODE                          588K        1 
mapped file                       51.5M        9 
shared memory                       40K        4 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              2.5G     1888 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space     1.4G     1888 

Model: iMac18,2, BootROM 429.60.3.0.0, 4 processors, Quad-Core Intel Core i7, 3.6 GHz, 32 GB, SMC 2.40f1
Graphics: kHW_AMDRadeonPro560Item, Radeon Pro 560, spdisplays_pcie_device, 4 GB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 16 GB, DDR4 SO-DIMM, 2400 MHz, 0x802C, 0x313641544632473634485A2D3247334232202020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 16 GB, DDR4 SO-DIMM, 2400 MHz, 0x802C, 0x313641544632473634485A2D3247334232202020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x16E), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.111.1 AirPortDriverBrcmNIC-1675.1)
Bluetooth: Version 8.0.2f9, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: AS2105
USB Device: USB 2.0 BILLBOARD
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Scarlett 2i4 USB
USB Device: My Passport 0827
Thunderbolt Bus: iMac, Apple Inc., 41.4
```

Comment: Posting code as image makes it really hard to do any experiments with your code. Could you try to make a minimal reproducible example out of this?

Comment: @LydiavanDyke thank you for your comment! I will edit the post.

Comment: @LydiavanDyke Should I also post the very lengthy error report that pops up? It exceeds the length of what's allowed

Comment: Can you figure out the relevant part of the error report? Usually interesting stuff is only at the beginning or at the end... Your code runs fine on my machine (linux, python 3.6.9 and nltk 3.5). So the error report is all we got at the moment.

Comment: @LydiavanDyke added the beginning and end of the crash report.

Comment: @LydiavanDyke I have also posted the full crash report on github: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/2647